# Existence and uniqueness of $y'=\sqrt{x-y}, \quad y(2)=2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Assume the IVP
$$
y'=\sqrt{x-y}=f(x,y), \quad y(2)=2
$$
Since there's no region of the form 
$$ 
R=\Big\{(x,y): |x-2|\leq 2 , |y-2| \leq 2 \Big\}
$$
in which $f$ is continuous, does it mean that Picard's theorem is undecidable about  existence?

Could another theorem tell us for sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider instead the equation $y' = \sqrt{|x-y|}$, where the right side is continuous on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.  Thus Picard says the initial value problem $y' = \sqrt{|x-y|}, y(2)=2$ has a solution in some interval $(2-\delta, 2+\delta)$.  It's not hard to show that this solution satisfies $y \le x$ for $x \in [2, 2+\delta)$, therefore it is a solution to your initial value problem in that interval.  On the other hand, for $x$ slightly less than $2$ we would have $y > x$, so it can't satisfy your differential equation there.

Comment: Thanks! Does Picard says anything about uniqueness? Is $f(x,y)=\sqrt{|x-y|}$ Lipschitz with respect to $y$?

Comment: No, it is not Lipschitz.  But note that the set of solutions is invariant under $(x,y) \to (x+c,y+c)$.  This should imply uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce $u=x-y$, then your equation leads to
$$
u'=1-\sqrt{|u|}
$$
which is separable. As the right side is different from $0$ close to $u(2)=0$, the integral in
$$
G(u)=\int_0^u \frac{dv}{1-\sqrt{|v|}}=t-2
$$
exists and the anti-derivative can be locally and uniquely solved for $u$ by the inverse function theorem, as $G'(0)=1$.